# Keycloak - Restrict login to client to members of a group

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I’m currently using Keycloak as a solution for handling login to my application. I’m using Spring, but not using the Keycloak adapter, but instead using the `.oauth2Login()` in my security config chain.

I’ve attempted to implement a policy within Keycloak, to ensure users are a member of a group to no avail. I’ve even gone as far as implementing a JS policy which exclusively consists of `$evaluation.deny()`, which, as far as I know should prevent all login attempts to the client. This, however, doesn’t do anything, instead, *any* user (who exists on the LDAP server) is able to login.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps on the [Activiti project](https://github.com/Activiti) we're using keycloak and we apply policies based on the group that a user belongs to. We've found it easy to restrict access based [on role](https://github.com/Activiti/example-runtime-bundle/blob/2a0d64f0cf58eda42d7aec7a44fbc0d4e0327190/src/main/resources/application.properties#L23) using the keycloak spring boot adapter but [groups](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/server_admin/topics/groups/groups-vs-roles.html) is more tricky. For this we [wrote code to look up the user's groups](https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-service-common/blob/eca4dd2215f4f7aad8e53deb8d8e2aedb3630054/activiti-cloud-services-common-identity-keycloak/src/main/java/org/activiti/cloud/services/identity/keycloak/KeycloakUserGroupManager.java#L41) using the keycloak java SDK and then at application level we filter what the user can see based on that - actually [based on restrictions that can be passed in at deploy time](https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/blob/fcdcac3d9dced49ad789660b9731e92f9ce8a9ba/activiti-cloud-full-example/values.yaml#L18).

The keycloak java sdk just calls out to keycloak's REST API so in your case perhaps you could call the REST API from your javascript to find out which groups the user is a member of (which I guess you've configured keycloak to pull from LDAP).

I don't know of any out of the box way to do the restrictions you're looking for from keycloak as the methods of restriction are geared towards roles rather than groups. Perhaps it would be possible if you were to use the [role mapper](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/1.9/server_admin_guide/topics/user-federation/ldap.html) but I don't know much about that.